# Time comparison for various zones in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I am developing an application for US based client. There is a functionality that user can not park a vehicle for more than 4 hours. My database time is stored in UTC.

I have below line in my view file to not to display vehicles who have already passed four hours since they have parked vehicles,

```
<% if (@vehicle.arrival_date == Date.current)%>
    <% if Time.current < (@vehicle.arrival_time + 4.hours) %> 
       <%= @vehicle.license_plate %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There is an issue with time zone, because I can find expected results in India, but client can not in USA. How can I make use of below code in order to query proper results. How can I use **in_time_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)')** method rails method??

I am allowing user to choose their time_zone so that they can view expected results,

```
<%= f.select :time_zone, (ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map{|zone| zone.name}),{:selected => @vehicle.time_zone }%>
```

I am trying to modify the above condition like so,

```
<% if (@vehicle.arrival_date.in_time_zone(@vehicle.time_zone) ==  Date.current.in_time_zone(ValidatedVehicle.last.time_zone)
)%>
  <% if Time.current.in_time_zone(@vehicle.time_zone) < (validated_vehicle.arrival_time.in_time_zone(@vehicle.time_zone) + 4.hours) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But not sure whether it is right way or not?

Comment: Hello @Hemant
So you want to set default time zone right?

Comment: Setting default time zone is not working for me. I set it to 'Central Time (US & Canada)', but that did not work for me. There are differences in 'Central Time (US & Canada)' and 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'....that might be the reason for unexpected results

Comment: Can you post the default TimeZone code from `config/application.rb` file

Comment: I commented it. So it defaults to UTC

Comment: Check my below answer it will help you.

Comment: If not working then let me know.

Comment: But how do I test it ....It works perfect in India, but how do I test it in US perspective

Comment: You have to test it after edit `application.rb` restart your server then create a new record, then display the created DateTime in human readable then search into google for current NY time then compare it @HemantPatil